# How to sync two SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, synchronization

I have two SQL Server 2008 databases with the same structure.

One is local and one is online. Data is inserted into local database, and then I want to sync with the online database.

Some of the data will also be updated on the online database by a c# win app. So I want to sync this data with local database.

What is the best solution for these requirements?

Answer (score 3):

Replication? MS Sync framework?

The manual? At least replication is something anyone working with SQL Server should have heard of. It only is part of SQL Server for about 15 years now, or so, since version 7. And documented.